# What's more secure for server side programming, Adobe Flash Media Server or PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, flash-media-server

I want to create a Flash application that sends information to a web server and I want the information to be encrypted and secured as good as possible.

I know that using Adobe Flash Media Server or Wowza it's possible to have some sort of JavaScript server side programming (ASC) and to send and fetch information using the RTMPE protocol. Is it in any way more secure than PHP for server side programming and using some other secure protocol to transfer information between the server and the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### adobe flash media server

1. adobe flash media server provides persistent connection which can show you exactly when the user used the application and for how long.
2. adobe flash media server provides RTMPE protocol (encrypted real time messaging protocol) which allows secure transfer of data without using ssl. RTMPE is faster than SSL and does not require certificate management as SSL does. specifications at http://lkcl.net/rtmp/RTMPE.txt
3. adobe flash media server provides a helpful admin page that shows how many users are connected to each instance of application and show how many resources are used per instance
4. adobe flash media server admin provides very useful debugging and tracing capabilities.

### PHP

1. the requests can be sent by ssl (https) which is very secured
2. amfphp - AMF allows for binary serialization of Action Script (AS2, AS3) native types and objects to be sent to server side services.
3. monitoring can easily be achieved by installing any monitoring tools that work with your web server (apache in my case)

#### conclusion

for now i'll stick to adobe flash media server till I'll find secured and easier methods to use with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think both do have security in their own directions. You have to decide which one you want to go with. However, you need to know about most if not all security considerations of both to be able to come up with something more secure.

Comment: the server itself will be very secured using both solutions. but using adobe flash media server, it's persistent connection which will allow me to see exactly how much time the user used the application.